# Demonstrating bound on integral

Tags: inequalities, integration

I found this question on another forum and it got me interested because of how tight the bound is: prove that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2 + 4}\,dx > \frac{\pi}{4}.$$
The difference between the two sides of the inequality is less than 0.00027. Using an obvious Feynman trick, we can transform the integral into
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\,d x}{x}\left(\frac{\log(1+x)}{2 + x} - \frac{\log(1-x)}{2-x}\right)$$
which allows a simple Taylor series, but because of how tight the inequality is, it takes many terms to prove it. I feel like either I am missing a good bit of knowledge to figure this out, or a non-obvious trick. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The obvious Feynman trick is not so obvious to me. Does it involve using the complex representation $2i\arctan z =\log \frac{i-z}{i+z}$ and replacing the integral along the real line by one along the imaginary axis (closing the contour along a quarter circle)?

Comment: No, it represents $\arctan(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{t^2x^2+1}\,dt$ and then Fubini.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral in question is $I(1-)$, where
$$I(u):=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^u\frac{\,d x}{x}(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{2 + x} - \frac{\ln(1-x)}{2-x})\\ 
=\frac{1}{4} (-\text{Li}_2(-u-1)+\text{Li}_2(u-1)-\text{Li}_2(-u)+\text{Li}_2(u)\\ 
+\ln(1-u) \ln(2-u)-\ln(u+1) \ln(u+2)),$$
so that
$$I(1-)=\frac{1}{16} (\pi ^2-4 (\text{Li}_2(-2)+\ln2\, \ln3)),$$
where $\text{Li}_2$ is the dilogarithm.

Next, to evaluate $\text{Li}_2(-2)$, use the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm)
$${\displaystyle \operatorname {Li} _{2}(z)+\operatorname {Li} _{2}(1/z)
=-{\frac {1}{6}}\pi ^{2}-{\frac {1}{2}}\ln^{2}(-z)}$$
for $z\notin[0,1)$ with $z=-2$, to get
$$\text{Li}_2(-2)
=-\frac {1}{6}\pi ^{2}-\frac {1}{2}\ln^{2}2-\text{Li}_2(-1/2) \\ 
=-\frac {1}{6}\pi ^{2}-\frac {1}{2}\ln^{2}2-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-1/2)^k}{k^2},$$
with the latter series converging geometrically fast.

More specifically, letting
\begin{equation}
d_K:=   -\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{1}{16} (\pi ^2-4 \ln3\, \ln3)+\frac{1}{4}
   \Big(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}+\frac{\ln ^2 2}{2}+\sum _{k=1}^K
   \frac{(-1/2)^k}{k^2}\Big),
\end{equation}
we see that
\begin{equation}
    I(1-)-\frac\pi4>d_4+\frac14\frac{(-1/2)^5}{5^2}
    >0.0004965-0.0003125>0.\quad\Box
\end{equation}